# Solr vs 'this' word

Tags: search, solr

There is a smal problem with solr. When I try to search text containing the word 'this' by issuing 'this' in the search console, solr doesn't find anything. However  there are no problems with other words. Is it sort of reserved word or something like that?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, 'this' is included in the list of default **stop words**.  Please see the section titled [solr.StopFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) in the docs.  Please also see the [solr.KeepWordFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeepWordFilterFactory) section.

Comment: jscott: thank you! now I know that it is not a bug :)
so, I found the file solr/conf/stopwords.txt with the list of these stop words. Also I found the following lines in schema.xml

<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />

So I guess Solr reads the list of these words from stopwords.txt. But when I delete the word 'this' from stopwords.txt and then restart solr nothing actually happens - I'm still not able to find anything by issuing 'this' in search console. 

And by the way, what is the point in using stop words?

Answer (score 1):

The point of stopwords are that they are very common words that aren't very useful to search for (nearly every document will contain 'the').

The reason you still can't find 'this' is probably because you were using the StopFilter when indexing the stop words weren't indexed.